# Function Escada

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando javascript agora e tenho uma dúvida em como fazer um programa de escada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
function escada(numero) {

  var arrayEscada = [];

  var espaco = " ";
  var traco = "#";

  for (var i = 0; i < numero ; i++) {

     numero = numero - 1;
     arrayEscada.push(espaco * numero);
     arrayEscada.push(traco * (i + 1) );

  }

  return arrayEscada;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema está no fato de que, diferentemente de outras linguagens, para repetir um caractere no JavaScript, você não pode fazer algo assim:

```
'#' * 5; // NaN
```

Deve usar o método [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

Enfim, você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function escada(degraus) {
  const escadaArray = [];
  const espacoChar = ' ';
  const degrauChar = '#';

  for (let i = 1; i <= degraus; i++) {
    const espacosParaAdd = espacoChar.repeat(degraus - i);
    const degrausParaAdd = degrauChar.repeat(i);

    escadaArray.push(espacosParaAdd + degrausParaAdd);
  }

  return escadaArray;
}

console.log(escada(3));
console.log(escada(5));
```

Algumas notas em relação ao exemplo acima:

1. Definimos o número de degraus de cada *andar* a partir da variável (`i`), que é incrementada a cada iteração;
2. Para calcular o número de espaços para ser colocado antes do degrau, basta subtrair o número total de degraus do número de degraus da iteração atual (`i`).

---

Indo um pouco mais além, se você quiser uma solução um pouco menos imperativa, pode fazer assim também (exemplo um *pouco mais* avançado):

```js
function makeStair(steps, step = '#', space = ' ') {
  return Array.from(
    { length: steps },
    (el, i) => space.repeat(steps - i) + step.repeat(++i)
  );
}

console.log(makeStair(3));
console.log(makeStair(5));
```

#### Leitura recomendada:

- [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat);
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from);
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).